# How to get correct country wise data in google analytic?

Tags: google-analytics

It looks like my country wise data in google analytic is wrong or else I'm unable to understand the way that GA track Geography data.

My total monthly users is 1.3 million and when I go for country wise data then India has 1.5 million unique users.

Why my total website data is less than India data?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you are looking at the same metric User and User
2. Make sure you are not under sampling (there are no pre-aggregated report in GA with geo location)  - try selecting only one day (not today) and see if you get the right number